# accessing rootBundle in flutter unit test

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, assets

I am writing a unit test in my flutter app, seems I can't read json from assets in tests, but it works if I run app,

I use code below to read json as string :

```
var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/student_list.json");
```

How can I access jsons assets in tests?

Comment: AFAIK you can only access the bundles in a Widget test. I have not found a way to access them in a unit test.

Comment: @AVEbrahim, Have you got solution on this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 16):

Add this line as the first to be executed in your test and it will work and load the assets:

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

It will initialise everything before running your code and the assets will be accessible at that point.